# Is John 3:18 the words of Jesus, or of John?

Tags: john, jesus

Using Bible Gateway John 3:18 is shown to be the words of the author, John, in the [NIV](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%203:1-18&version=NIV) translation:

> Whoever believes in him is not condemned, but whoever does not believe stands condemned already because they have not believed in the name of God’s one and only Son.

But in [NKJV](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%203:1-18&version=NKJV), they are shown as the words of Jesus:

> “He who believes in Him is not condemned; but he who does not believe is condemned already, because he has not believed in the name of the only begotten Son of God."

What evidence exists for whether these are words of Jesus or John?

Answer (score 3):

There are some who assert that a change in speaker *from* Jesus *to* the author John occurs in John 3:13. The evidence that John is speaking from John 3:13 forward is the change from first-person to third-person.

See related:
[To whom should we attribute John 3:16?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/4991/to-whom-should-we-attribute-john-316)

Ultimately, it comes down to translator bias or assumption since the original manuscripts were all majusculars with no punctuation and no spaces between letters. A translator's dream!

Comment: My opinion/ belief is that John is speaking from v. 13 on. Jesus = first-person, John = third-person in that chapter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I would be willing to consider this question a duplicate of the other, in fact.